# Dynamically add checkboxes with tkinter in python 2.7

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to dynamically add ckeckboxes to my gui through a premade list. How would I populate the GUI with the names in my list? They all have the same type of functionality, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the problem description. "dynamically" to me means that the checkboxes will be added/removed on the fly during run time. But "premade" implies that the list of names is established before the program starts, and doesn't change. So which is it?

Comment: I mean a list that is created during runtime when my csv parser populates the list with the names of the important columns. So it is a static list when the GUI is ran, but the csv parser dynamically imports the column names from an arbitrary csv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to populate your GUI with a premade list at startup:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

premadeList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

for checkBoxName in premadeList:
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxName)
    c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to dynamically populate your GUI with checkboxes at runtime:

```
import random
import string
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def addCheckBox():
    checkBoxName = "".join(random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(10))
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxName)
    c.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Add a checkbox", command=addCheckBox)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And of course, you can do both:

```
import random
import string
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def addCheckBox():
    checkBoxName = "".join(random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(10))
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxName)
    c.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Add a checkbox", command=addCheckBox)
b.pack()

premadeList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

for checkBoxName in premadeList:
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxName)
    c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a treeview with checkboxes.

[image: Treeview with checkboxes]

[How to create a tree view with checkboxes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104330/how-to-create-a-tree-view-with-checkboxes-in-python)