# Directory treeview with filetype filter and checkbox using ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk, tix

I have a GUI in python using Tkinter with multiple frames inside the main GUI. Added another frame to show a treeview of a directory (which will have sub directories as well) and filter to show only files of specific type. Then user selects file(s) by clicking on the checkbox shown to the left of every file to do further processing. I started off with [this](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/python/+/243b47fbef58ab866ee77567f2f52affd8ec8d0f/Python-2.7.3/Demo/tkinter/ttk/dirbrowser.py) sample. Is it possible to use ttk treeview with a checkbox to the left of each entry like in tix as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483980/creating-a-treeview-with-checkboxes)?

Basically would like to have all the subitems auto checked when a folder is checked etc. Just like how a windows explorer dialogs work.

any suggestions?

[image: Treeview]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the `CheckboxTreeview` widget from the [ttkwidgets](https://pypi.org/project/ttkwidgets/) module.
The documentation is available [here](https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets.CheckboxTreeview.html#ttkwidgets.CheckboxTreeview).

`CheckboxTreeview` inherits from `ttk.Treeview`, so you can create a column for the file size just like in a regular `ttk.Treeview`, with the `columns` option. Then you can set the columns' labels with the

```
tree.heading(<column>, text=<label>)
```

Finally if you want to change the style of the checkboxes, you can do so by replacing them with you own images. The 3 checkbox states are done using the images: `tree.im_checked`, `tree.im_unchecked`, `tree.im_tristate`. You can replace them with

```
tree.im_checked.paste(<new PIL image>)
```

Here is the full code:

```
from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()

tree = CheckboxTreeview(root, columns=['Size'])
tree.im_checked.paste(Image.open('path/to/image'))
tree.im_unchecked.paste(Image.open('path/to/image'))
tree.im_tristate.paste(Image.open('path/to/image'))
tree.pack()

tree.heading('#0', text='Directory structure', anchor='w')
tree.heading('#1', text='File size', anchor='w')
tree.insert("", "end", "1", text="1")
tree.insert("1", "end", "11", text="11")
tree.insert("1", "end", "12",  text="12", values=['2 bytes'])
tree.insert("11", "end", "111", text="111", values=['100 bytes'])
tree.insert("", "end", "2", text="2", values=['20 bytes'])

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I did come across this, but I didnt see any options to change the background / foreground colors to match rest of the GUI and also would like to show the size of the file as well (as shown in my first picture, maybe by using 'tag_add'). Will play with it more and see if I can get it to work as I like.

Comment: Like with a regular treeview, you can add columns and as for the checkboxes, they are made with pictures so you can change them.