# Value gets vanished when i check a checkbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, tix

When I check a checkbox in Tkinter the value of checkbox gets vanished.

This problem appears in Linux only.

The same code I am using in windows and it is working Fine.

I Referred this link to make this gui

[How to create a tree view with checkboxes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104330/how-to-create-a-tree-view-with-checkboxes-in-python)

**Code:**

```
import Tkinter as tk

import Tix as tix

def  selectItem(item):
        
    if cl.getstatus(item) == 'on':
        print("Checked")
    if cl.getstatus(item) == 'off':
        print("Unchecked")

root = tix.Tk()
cl = tix.CheckList(root,browsecmd=selectItem)
cl.pack()
cl.hlist.add("CL1", text="Test")
cl.setstatus("CL1","off")
cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item1", text="child")
cl.setstatus("CL1.Item1","off")
root.mainloop()
```

**Before check :**

[image]

**After check :**

[image]

As you can see in the image that checkbox `Test` disappears after click on Test.This problem is happening only in Linux.Can anyone Give me any Solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Actually the colour of background and foreground was same.therefore i changed the colour of foreground and background.

```
import Tkinter as tk

import Tix as tix

def  selectItem(item):

    if cl.getstatus(item) == 'on':
        print("Checked")
    if cl.getstatus(item) == 'off':
        print("Unchecked")

root = tix.Tk()
cl = tix.CheckList(root,browsecmd=selectItem)
cl.hlist.config(bg='White',bd=0,selectmode='none',selectbackground='white',selectforeground='black',drawbranch=True)
cl.pack()
cl.hlist.add("CL1", text="Test")
cl.setstatus("CL1","off")
cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item1", text="child")
cl.setstatus("CL1.Item1","off")
root.mainloop()
```