# How Can I add checkbox in ttk Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I searched very much for this answer,Then I came to know that we can't embedded widgets into Treeview But I found the Features of Treeview. 
In this below Features It is telling that Treeview will support of including 
checkbox also.

Here is a list of TreeView features:

```
Auto-sizing column widths and row heights.
Hide/move columns or nodes.
Sortable by columns or sub-trees.
External data storage (in a blt::tree).
Multiple TreeViews can share all a tree.
Easy to use dynamic loading (for sub-trees).
Support for multiple style types, including:
    -> textbox: text cell with optional images.
    *-> checkbox: a boolean value.*
    -> combobox: a multi-choice value.
    -> barbox: numeric value with progress bar.
    -> windowbox: arbitrary embedded windows. 
Styles can be applied to cols, rows and/or cells
The -altstyle option for alternating rows (bgcolor, etc).
The -levelstyles option for per-level styles.
Background image-tile: widget, columns, and cell-styles.
Drop shadow text.
Powerful builtin cell editing.
Dual mode display: flat and tree.
```

Comment: Where did you get that list? I don't think that has anything to do with the ttk.TreeView widget.

Comment: http://pdqi.com/w/pw/pdqi/Wize/TreeView. In this link at the bottom of the page you will find the features of Treeview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a tree view with checkboxes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104330/how-to-create-a-tree-view-with-checkboxes-in-python)

Comment: the Wize TreeView is not the treeview that comes with tkinter. It's a separate package.