# Creating Hierarchical checkbox tree view in tkinter using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tix, hierarchical-trees

```
import tkinter.tix as Tix

class View(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.makeCheckList()

    def makeCheckList(self):
        self.cl = Tix.CheckList(self.root,height=200,width=400)
        self.cl.pack()
        self.cl.hlist.add("C", text="GeeksforGeeks")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1", text="Computer Science")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1.Item1", text="Algorithm")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1.Item2", text="Data Structures")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL2", text="Gate Paper")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL2.Item1", text="2018 paper")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL2.Item2", text="2019 paper")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL3", text="Programming language")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL3.Item1", text="Python")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL3.Item2", text="java")

        self.cl.setstatus("C", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1.Item2", "off")

        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL2", "on")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL2.Item1")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL2.Item2")

        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL3", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL3.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL3.Item2", "off")
        self.cl.autosetmode()

def main():
    root = Tix.Tk()
    view = View(root)
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Refer the image, adding checkbox to the tree view and if I select GeeksforGeeks it should select All sub elements, if I select Programming language it should select both python and java. same should work for unselect also

source code- [How to create a tree view with checkboxes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104330/how-to-create-a-tree-view-with-checkboxes-in-python)

Comment: Can You show Your code/what You have tried.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5104330/12198502)

Comment: @JacksonPro that is good. but in that if i select checklist1, it wont select subitem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in method to do that. You might need to loop through children to set the checkbox

Sample code that has two methods `select_child` for selecting the first level children and `select_children` for selecting all the children.

```py
import tkinter.tix as Tix

class View(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.makeCheckList()

    def makeCheckList(self):
        #self.cl = Tix.CheckList(self.root, command=self.select_child, browsecmd=self.select_child)
        self.cl = Tix.CheckList(self.root, command=self.select_children, browsecmd=self.select_children)
        self.cl.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        self.cl.hlist.add("C", text="Top")
        #self.cl.hlist.bind("<Button-1>", self.select)

        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1", text="Computer Science")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1.Item1", text="Algorithm")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1.Item2", text="Data Structures")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL1.Item2.Item3", text="python")

        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL2", text="Gate Paper")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL2.Item1", text="2018 paper")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL2.Item2", text="2019 paper")

        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL3", text="Programming language")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL3.Item1", text="Python")
        self.cl.hlist.add("C.CL3.Item2", text="java")

        self.cl.setstatus("C", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1.Item2", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL1.Item2.Item3", "off")

        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL2", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL2.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL2.Item2", "off")

        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL3", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL3.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("C.CL3.Item2", "off")
        self.cl.autosetmode()

    def select_children(self, item):  # selects all the children

        children = self.cl.hlist.info_children(item)
        status = self.cl.getstatus(item)
        
        for child in children:
            self.cl.setstatus(child, status)
            grand_child = self.cl.hlist.info_children(child)
            while grand_child:
                for x in grand_child:
                    self.cl.setstatus(x, status)
                    grand_child = self.cl.hlist.info_children(x)
            

    def select_child(self, item):  # selects only the first level children
        children = self.cl.hlist.info_children(item)
        status = self.cl.getstatus(item)

        for child in children:
            self.cl.setstatus(child, status)
        
def main():
    root = Tix.Tk()
    view = View(root)
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

refer these docs [1](http://tix.sourceforge.net/man/html/TixCmd/tixHList.htm#M2) [2](http://tix.sourceforge.net/dist/current/man/html/TixCmd/tixCheckList.htm#M2)